# Pun on words: how to quickly and accurately understand pun in a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Reaching the bottom of a case
>
> I was intrigued to read in The world this week (October 24th) that Brazilian police had raided a senator’s home and discovered about $5,000 wedged between his buttocks. He has denied diverting funds that were meant for the pandemic. If he is innocent then this is a most unfortunate case of a bum rap.

This is a letter published on *the* *economist*, I believe there is a lot of word play. And I did some search and found Lot Lick answer inspiring to another related question. Can you further explain the play on the words: case, bottom/bum/buttocks, and rap?
Of there is more word play, please enlighten me as well.

Comment: I don't see much word play, I see one pun based on the multiple meanings of *bum*.

Comment: "A bum <something>" in American informal speech  is something incorrect or worthless. For example "A bum note" is a wrong note played on an instrument. Also in American informal speech "a rap" can be a criminal charge leading to arrest. "A bum rap" therefore is a criminal charge leading to arrest which proves not to be supported by evidence. "A person's bum" in British informal speech usually means their buttocks, or that part of their body in general. The pun is a play on the AmE and BrE meanings of "bum" related to the senator's choice of hiding place for the money.

Comment: That’s a cheeky way to divert funds.

Comment: Maybe he just had money coming out the wazoo.

Comment: As to the question in your title, there's no general way to quickly and accurately understand a pun.  Some are blatantly obvious, while others are quite subtle and convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by StephenS I am converting my comment to an answer.

"A bum " in American informal speech is something incorrect or worthless. For example "A bum note" is a wrong note played on an instrument.

Also in American informal speech "a rap" can be a criminal charge leading to arrest. "A bum rap" therefore is a criminal charge leading to arrest which proves not to be supported by evidence.

"A person's bum" in British informal speech usually means their buttocks, their 'bottom', or that part of their body in general.

The pun is a play on the AmE and BrE meanings of "bum" related to the senator's choice of hiding place for the money.

Comment: I don't know if I've heard “a bum note”, but I have used “my bum shoulder” meaning the shoulder that, because of old injury, I cannot use as fully as the other.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I imagine you are American, to me your having  "a bum shoulder" would indicate that your anatomy was very seriously compromised:-). Having said that I was aware that I was going to miss many of the American uses of "bum", partly because I'm not embedded in the culture, but also because trying to list even all the ones of which I was aware would have taken too long and just been confusing, particularly for a non-native speaker.